# different function type when using if statement in Rust

Tags: if-statement, rust

I'm new in rust and i need to make a small if statement on function option for example

```rust
use isahc::{
    HttpClient, 
    config::{
        RedirectPolicy, 
        VersionNegotiation,
        SslOption}, 
    prelude::*
};

use std::{
    time::Duration
};

pub struct http {
    pub timeout: u64    
}





impl http {
    pub fn send(&self) -> HttpClient  {
        let client = 
            HttpClient::builder()
                .version_negotiation(VersionNegotiation::http11())
                .redirect_policy(RedirectPolicy::None)
                .timeout(Duration::from_secs(self.timeout));
                .ssl_options(SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_INVALID_CERTS | SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_REVOKED_CERTS);
        return client.build().unwrap();
    }

    }

fn main(){
    let req = http{ timeout:"20".parse().unwrap()};
    let test = req.send();
    test.get("https://www.google.com");
}
```

now in my program the user will give me the options of the request (eg: follow redirects or not ) and this need `if statement` on these options so i tried to use it on this case  but i always get a different function return type

```rust
impl http {
    pub fn send(&self) -> HttpClient  {
        let client = 
            HttpClient::builder()
                .version_negotiation(VersionNegotiation::http11())
                .redirect_policy(RedirectPolicy::None)
                .ssl_options(SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_INVALID_CERTS | SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_REVOKED_CERTS);
        if 1 == 1 {
            client.timeout(Duration::from_secs(self.timeout));
        }
        return client.build().unwrap();
    }

    }
```

- Cargo Output

```sh
warning: type `http` should have an upper camel case name
  --> src/sender.rs:14:12
   |
14 | pub struct http {
   |            ^^^^ help: convert the identifier to upper camel case: `Http`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(non_camel_case_types)]` on by default

error[E0382]: use of moved value: `client`
  --> src/sender.rs:32:16
   |
24 |         let client = 
   |             ------ move occurs because `client` has type `HttpClientBuilder`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
30 |             client.timeout(Duration::from_secs(self.timeout));
   |             ------ value moved here
31 |         }
32 |         return client.build().unwrap();
   |                ^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

so what I'm doing wrong ?
i tired to change the function type exception but i can't use the function of the class `client.get()` for example

- this a clear example in python for explain what i need to do

```py
options : dict = {
  "redirects": False,
  "ssl_path":"~/cer.pem"
}


def send(opts):
   # not real httplib ! 
   r = httplib.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
   if opts.get('redirects') == True:
       r.redirects = True
   if opts.get('cert_path',''):
       r.ssl = opts.get('cert_path')
   return r.send()

def main():
   send(options)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a builder pattern, each function call consumes the builder and returns it back. So you need to capture `client` from the return value of the `timeout` function in order to continue using it. Note that you also need to make `client` mutable.

Something like

```rust
impl http {
    pub fn send(&self) -> HttpClient  {
        let mut client = 
            HttpClient::builder()
                .version_negotiation(VersionNegotiation::http11())
                .redirect_policy(RedirectPolicy::None)
                .ssl_options(SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_INVALID_CERTS | SslOption::DANGER_ACCEPT_REVOKED_CERTS);
        if 1 == 1 {
            client = client.timeout(Duration::from_secs(self.timeout));
        }
        return client.build().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution and explanation :)